# assertHTMLEqual() via pytest

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I prefer [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to the Django way of testing.

It works fine, except that I don't know how to [assertHTMLEqual()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertHTMLEqual) via pytest.

How to assert that the HTML snippets are almost equal?

Answer (score 3):

Per the docs [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#assertions) it says:

> > All of Django’s TestCase Assertions are available in pytest_django.asserts

Taking a quick look at the source code [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/master/pytest_django/asserts.py#L27) we can see that it imports everything from `SimpleTestCase` which `assertHTMLEqual` is a part of.